# C# String comparison not working when compared with a value received over network

Tags: c#, string

I have a server asking for a value against a code. If the value of Code is "Admin", it will display "Working" else "Error" with the actual value of code.

```
ClientSend("Admin");
Code = ClientReceive();
if (Code.Equals("Admin"))
{
    DisplayAlert("Working", "Working", "OK");
}
else
    DisplayAlert("Error", Code, "OK");
```

The `ClientSend` function is working properly....

The `ClientReceive` function is:

```
public string ClientReceive()
{
    try
    {
        stream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] data;
        data = new Byte[256];
        String responseData = String.Empty;
        Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
        return responseData.Trim();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the target server, I have a code which says:

```
if (e.MessageString.Equals("Admin"))
            e.ReplyLine(string.Format("Admin"));
```

Now when I am executing the code, I am receiving an error alert....
The funniest thing is that the value of "code" received is "Admin"....
This is confirmed when the error alert shows the output as "Admin"....

Then why is `Code.Equals("Admin")` giving a negative response?

Comment: I think debugging it and seeing why its different is going to be the best method of figuring it out

Comment: There are some letters that **look** the same but aren't. Compare the first character vs the first, then the second vs the second to narrow it down.

Comment: If those streams are network streams running on TCP, be aware that TCP isn't **messaging**. You're not guaranteed that a call to `Read` at one end will precisely match a single call to `Write` from the other end. I would guess at some additional whitespace that you're not accounting for, but we'd need all of the function defns to be sure. Despite your assurance that they're "working properly".

Comment: You are assuming ASCII. When the server sends UTF8 (with a BOM maybe) you could be in error. Most crucial check: is `bytes == 5` ?  What is `ReplyLine()` ?

Comment: It would be helpful to also see the ClientSend function. :)

Comment: Thanks @bommelding ...
Now that I have changed my **ClientReceive()** code to `data = new Byte[5];` , the String comparison is working... But this is not a long term solution as the incoming response may not be of just 5 bytes... Kindly suggest how to ensure that the string comparison works for all response...

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be in the code you're showing us. (Psychic prediction time) - *somewhere* you're working with an oversize buffer and *not* correctly only working with the portion of it containing actual data (you actually have this correct in `ClientReceive` where you do `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);` rather than `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, data.Length);` or `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);`, both common errors), and so ending up with a buffer containing both the text `Admin` and some trailing `\0`s. Those aren't whitespace, so aren't trimmed.

Comment: Set it back to 256 and tell us what the value of `bytes` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the presence of an empty character in the end which failed the comparison.

When the Code.Length was checked it was 6 while the length of Admin was 5.

Thus the error was removed by taking a substring of the responseData without the last empty character.

```
public string ClientReceive()
    {
        try
        {
            stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] data;
            data = new Byte[256];
            String responseData = String.Empty;
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            responseData = responseData.Substring(0, responseData.Length-1); // This will remove the last character
            return responseData;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Special Thanks to @bommelding and @Damien_The_Unbelievable for directing me to the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that e.ReplyLine(string.Format("Admin")); replies with a line of text including a line delimiter (CRLF).